# How can I create recurring hierarchical files and directories?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.0

I have to recursively create files and directories in the projects I develop. For example, if I'm using the MVVM architecture, I'm constantly creating directories like view, model, model_view for a component in project structure.

Naturally, my question is, does android studio include a feature for these repetitive directory and file operations?

If so, what is the name of this feature?

How can I create this hierarchy more rationally in android studio?;

```
component_name/
              model
                   /params.dart
              view
                  /view.dart
              view_model
                        /view_model.dart
```

I searched this question on the internet, but I could not reach the result I was looking for from the results related to android, so I apologize if this question has been asked before.